# Angular 8 - Routing not working when click on menu bar where mentioned route path in href

Tags: angular, angular8, iis-8

Thanks In Advance:

I am trying to click menu bar where I have mentioned href to routing path and hosted on IIS. when I click on menu on UI it nothing happening and not going to respective component.It going to default route path. but it working in local port 4200.
when I click on menu bar page is get refreshed. I am trying hard from many days but it helpless can someone please assist me to get correct implementation.

**This is my component HTML where i have given href to route path.**

Fresh Vegetable

```
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown">
            <a href="Wheat" class="dropdown-toggle"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="menu-icon fa fa-cogs"></i>Wheat</a>                    
        </li>
```

**

**This is my Route:**

```
{
  path:'Veg',
  component:VegetablesComponent,
  canActivate :[AuthGuard] 
},
```

**This is my Index**

```
 <base href="./">
```

**This is my Web config in IIS**

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/ePortal/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your anchor  will always refresh your app since angular doesn't get notified to intercept it.

Use `<a routerLink="/first-component">` instead.

For more information, see: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: I think it is "anchor" in English. :-)